# Provisioning a vagrantfile using json

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtual-machine

Hey so i want to provision my vagrantfile using json, i have done this with yaml before and tried to follow the syntax alongside a little research on json. I have included print commands to confirm that the values from my json are readable but im struggling in understanding how to put them into my code as values? so my question is how do i call these values within a vagrant file?

```
require 'json'
filej = File.read('info.json')
jinfo = JSON.parse(filej)
vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  jinfo.each do |key, value|
    p key
    p value

    config.vm.define jinfo['name'] do |js|
      js.vm.box = jinfo['box']
      js.vm.network 'private_network', ip: js['ip_addr']
      js.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.cpus = jinfo['vcpu']
        vb.memory = jinfo['ram']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and my json is as follows

```
[
  {
    "name": "jenkins",
    "box": "centos/7",
    "ram": 4096,
    "vcpu": 2,
    "ip_addr": "192.168.33.11"
  },
  {
    "name": "server",
    "box": "centos/7",
    "ram": 4096,
    "vcpu": 2,
    "ip_addr": "192.168.33.10"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Vagrantfile is same as pasted above, it looks like this:

```
require 'json'
filej = File.read('info.json')
jinfo = JSON.parse(filej)
vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  jinfo.each do |key, value|
    p key
    p value

    config.vm.define jinfo['name'] do |js|
      js.vm.box = jinfo['box']
      js.vm.network 'private_network', ip: js['ip_addr']
      js.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.cpus = jinfo['vcpu']
        vb.memory = jinfo['ram']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`jinfo` is actually an array and not a hash. You are trying to loop through each key value pair of the json instead of looping through each value. Try this:

```
require 'json'
filej = File.read('info.json')
jinfos = JSON.parse(filej)
vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  jinfos.each do |jinfo|
    p jinfo

    config.vm.define jinfo['name'] do |js|
      js.vm.box = jinfo['box']
      js.vm.network 'private_network', ip: js['ip_addr']
      js.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.cpus = jinfo['vcpu']
        vb.memory = jinfo['ram']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I changed the variable names slightly. You can remove the print part altogether and try.

Hope this helped.